# Scala Higher Order Functions and Implicit Typing

Tags: scala, functional-programming, type-inference

I recently started working with *Functional Programming in Scala* and am learning Scala in the process. While attempting one of the Chapter 2 exercises to define a function that curries another function, I ran into this:

If I write

```
def curry[A,B,C](f: (A,B) => C): A => B => C =
    a: A => b: B => f(a, b)
```

then I get

> Chapter2.scala:49: error: ';' expected but ':' found.
>   a: A => b: B => f(a, b)
>   _______^
>   one error found

BUT if I write

```
def curry[A,B,C](f: (A,B) => C): A => B => C =
    a => b => f(a, b)
```

then it compiles fine, with no warnings, and works. What's the difference?

Comment: Well the difference is obviously that the first example is not syntactically correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to enclose your variables in parentheses. In your example,
you can write:

```
def curry[A,B,C](f: (A,B) => C): A => B => C =
  (a: A) => (b: B) => f(a, b)
```

Comment: This is a quirk to me; is there an explicit reason why?

Comment: In general, parentheses are required in `a: A => ...` form; they are only allowed to be omitted when it is the last expression in a block. See http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#anonymous-functions.